# Looping through a file but ignoring the first two lines in Bash

Tags: bash, loops, diff

I am using the following command: `diff -u file1 file2 > diff.txt` and parsing the output. I have a loop that can iterate every line in the file. I am using a loop solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1521498/17386696.

```
while IFS="" read -r p || [ -n "$p" ] ; do
      # first character '+'
      if [[ ${p:0:1} = "+" ]] ; then
        # do something
      # first character '-'
      elif [[ ${p:0:1} = "-" ]] ; then
        # do something
      fi
    done < diff.txt
```

My current issue is that the first two lines of the file look like:

```
--- file1  2022-03-19 12:28:10.119916406 -0400
+++ file2  2022-03-19 12:28:11.171926970 -0400
```

I know I could create another conditional statement for the `+++` and `---` lines if all else fails. I was curious if there was a way to adjust the loop to start at line three to avoid the triple symbols.

Comment: try `done < <(tail +3 diff.txt)` or `done < <(tail -n +3 diff.txt)`

Comment: also `done < <(sed '1,2d' diff.txt)` and `done < <(awk 'NR>2' diff.txt)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the small number of lines (2) to be ignored, I suggest the following:

```
{
  read; read
  while IFS="" read -r p || [ -n "$p" ] ; do
    ...
  done
} < diff.txt
```

`read; read` reads the first two lines from stdin (diff.txt).

Comment: It works! Wondering if you could explain what the curly braces are doing? I do not fully understand them.

Comment: `{ ...; }` is a compound command. In it all commands can read from same stdin (`diff.txt`).